# Emploi du mot 'moult'

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, synonymes

> moult \mult\ invariable
>
> (Vieilli) Beaucoup. Note d’usage : Attaché à un verbe. À mon avis, le
> véritable test s’est présenté à la rentrée scolaire d’automne, dans un
> contexte où tant les parents, les profs que les directions d’école
> avaient des récriminations contre le ministre, à qui l’on reprochait
> moult tergiversations à l’approche du moment crucial. — (Rémi Nadeau,
> Roberge est encore l’homme de Legault, Le Journal de Québec, 30
> janvier 2021) Nous contribuons en réfléchissant moult.

> (Vieilli) ou
> (Ironique) Très, bien, fort. Note d’usage : Attaché à un adjectif.
> C’est moult compliqué à expliquer !

Source : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/moult

1. Peut-on utiliser moult couramment ?

J'ai rencontré des tournures avec moult+nom comme ci-dessous :

> [Après moult vicissitudes, le musée des Confluences sort peu à peu de terre à Lyon](https://www.challenges.fr/afp/apres-moult-vicissitudes-le-musee-des-confluences-sort-peu-a-peu-de-terre-a-lyon_300750)

> [Après moult polémiques](https://www.estrepublicain.fr/actualite/2020/01/16/un-nouveau-conservatoire-va-sortir-de-terre) et surtout près de quinze ans de retard, au vu de la vétusté et l’exiguïté des locaux existants (sur l’esplanade du château), la construction d’un nouveau conservatoire , dans le quartier des Blancheries à Montbéliard, a enfin été actée en 2019.

Ici, 'moult+nom' est utilisé au lieu de 'beaucoup de+nom'. Wiki ne parle pas de cet usage. Est-ce un emploi récent ? Est-il de registre soutenu ?